# What is the updated belief of B given F and I with all of them being independent?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

What is the updated belief of B given F and I with all of them being independent?

This is more of a smell check cause I'm decently sure I have the correct thought process but it seems weird in the context of the story:

"Say you are 20% sure GameStop stocks will go up in a week, but your friend says it will for sure go up and your friend is correct 60% of the time. Then say you talk to a professional investor and they say that the stock will go up and is correct 80% of the time. Assume your belief, your friend's accuracy and the investor's accuracy are all independent events. What is your updated belief after observing what your friend says? How about after observing your friend and the investor?"

So I'm decently sure it's 20% for both cases, because the events are independent. So let's call my belief event B, friend's correctness F and investor's correctness as I. Then $P(B|F)=\frac{P(B,F)}{P(F)}$, but since they're independent $P(B|F)=\frac{P(B)P(F)}{P(F)}=\frac{(0.2)(0.6)}{0.6}=0.2$ then also because I is independent of B and F then $P(B|F,I)=\frac{P(B,F,I)}{P(F,I)}=\frac{P(B)P(F)P(I)}{P(F)P(I)}=P(B)=0.2$. This all makes sense to me given that they're all independent and only the marginal probabilities are given, it'd be impossible to solve this if they weren't independent because the joints and conditionals are not given, but it feels weird that my belief wouldn't improve given my friends and investor's correctness as evidence.

Comment: It looks like part of the confusion here comes from calling two different things $B$. There's the event that you originally feel like the stock will go up, and the event that the stock actually will go up.

Comment: Also, "both say the stock rises" is not the same event as "both are correct".

Comment: Is what I wrote mathematically correct?

Comment: The equations you wrote are true of independent events, but you haven't correctly modeled the situation that you described in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $S$ the unknown event (i.e. that the stock is actually going to go up) and $A,B,C$ the events for the people's "hunches" (including your own, if you want).

It's reasonable to treat $A,B,C$ as independent given $S$, i.e. $P(A,B,C|S)=P(A|S)P(B|S)P(C|S)$, and you can model the different people's success rates using the conditional probabilities for each of the hunches (so e.g. $P(C|S)=P(\lnot C|\lnot S)=0.8$). Doing Bayesian inference to take the hunches into account means calculating $P(S|A,B,C)$, and this can definitely be different from $P(S)$ (and from $P(S|A)$, where $A$ is your own hunch).

With the information you gave, I'd leave out $A$ (since $P(S)$ already represents your prior belief in $S$). Then:
$$
\begin{align}
P(S|B,C)
&=\frac{P(S,B,C)}{P(B,C)}\\
&=\frac{P(S,B,C)}{P(S,B,C)+P(\lnot S,B,C)}\\
&=\frac{P(S)P(B|S)P(C|S)}{P(S)P(B|S)P(C|S)+P(\lnot S)P(B|\lnot S)P(C|\lnot S)}\\
&=\frac{(.2)(.6)(.8)}{(.2)(.6)(.8)+(.8)(.4)(.2)}\\
&=0.6
\end{align}$$

So hearing your friends' predictions increases your confidence from $0.2$ to $0.6$.

Comment: The question asks to calculate "updated belief" I don't think that means calculating the actual probability of S. I took it to mean calculate $P(B|F,I)$

Comment: In Bayesian statistics, probabilities represent beliefs. $P(S)$ is a "prior" probability representing your belief in $S$ before taking the hunches into account, and $P(S|A,B,C)$ is a "posterior" probability representing your belief in $S$ after taking them into account. Conditioning on new information is what gives us a "belief update".

Comment: So how would you solve the problem given all the information in my post? I don't have any of the conditional probabilities you wrote.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the calculation.

Comment: are you sure $P(A|\neg B)= 1-P(A|B)$? I thought it was $1-P(\neg A | \neg B)$

Comment: The general rule is just $P(\lnot A|B)=1-P(A|B)$, but we interpret "the friend is correct 60% of the time" as saying that both $P(B|S)=0.6$ and $P(\lnot B|\lnot S)=0.6$. (Remember that in this model, S is "the stock will actually go up" and B is "the friend says it will go up".)

Comment: awesome. Thanks so much.